# Как сделать подгрузку нового контента без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

В общении между клиентами нужно реализовать мгновенную подкачку последнего сообщения (т.е. если пользователь (А) отправил сообщение пользователю (Б), в их диалоге мгновенно подгружается это сообщение без перезагрузки страницы)Как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы пробовали ajax?

Comment: Сервер хранит сокеты каждого клиента, он должен озаботиться тем, чтобы оповестить пользователя Б о новом сообщении. Это один из способов решения вашего вопроса. Чтобы сервер хранил текущий сокет клиента, есть несколько способов, самый простой - хитрость, заключающаяся в том, что клиент шлёт простейший запрос, например check, а сервер в этот момент "затягивает" ответ. Затягивает его до тех пор, пока другой пользователь не совершит действие, после чего сервер отдаёт ответ, и клиент Б получает сообщение своевременно.

Comment: Как именно надо вытащить последнее сообщение ajax`oм??Некий вечный цикл или как?У меня нет опыта , я учусь только!

Comment: задача ajax в данном случае, послать сигнал "ожидания". Сервер примет сообщение, но, не завершит сессию работы с сокетом, и не ответит, а будет ждать в цикле. Когда второй человек ajax-ом пошлёт сообщение, все остальные задержанные сокеты должны ответить на запрос этим сообщением.

Comment: Ооо, вот как именно выглядит этот ajax-сигнал "ожидания"???
$.ajax({
                "url": "url...",
                'method': 'POST',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                'dataType': 'json',
                'data': JSON.stringify(request...)///
Так?А уже на сервере на этот запрос сделать цикл - который проверяет есть ли новое сообщение в диалоге, и если есть - то тогда дать ответ)Так?

Comment: @test123 это при использовании сокетов, человек спрашивает про обычную загрузку аяксом. тут вопрос в простой циклической проверке новых данных  на сервере, хотя мб и нет.

Comment: @teran, А, ну если его устраивает спамить запросами каждые n секунд - думаю, тут любое решение подойдёт...

Comment: >>Так?<< да, очень похоже) В качестве запроса придумайте любое кодовое слово. например "wait", и по этому кодовому слову, на стороне сервера, начинайте цикл с ожиданием. Далее, если на сервер приходит другое сообщение, не wait, все ожидающие должны завершить цикл, и подтянуть данные по новой (это сигнал о том, что кто то проявил активность и время качать актуальную информацию/сообщения)

Comment: Ясно, огромное спасибо, хоть теперь есть некое представление этой реализации)а то вообще незнал как)

Comment: На стороне клиента, так же, останется сделать цикл из двух команд - первая будет подтягивать текущие данные (тем же ajax-ом), вторая будет слать запрос wait. И так до бесконечности. Получится, что клиент обновит информацию, и будет ждать следующего ответа от сервера. Когда сервер отвечает, надо снова обновлять данные и снова переходить в ожидание.

Comment: а вот еще вопросик, что б не создавать новую тему - как еще реализовать прочитанное/непрочитанное собщение?тоже просто идейку надо)

Comment: Для статуса, зависит от того где эти сообщения. Самый простой способ, хранить у клиента список прочитанных сообщений в текущей сессии. Соответственно, делать при получении сообщении перебор и искать уникальные id. Есть вариант переложить эту работу на сервер, вести коллекцию сообщений (контейнер с текстом и со списком читавших сообщение пользователей, например Set), ну, сервер знает что он шлёт клиенту, поэтому может в любой момент добавить нового получателя в сообщение, тем самым запомнить что клиент уже получал сообщение, а значит читал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно реализовать с помощью

- Поллинга;
- Лонгполлинга;
- Бесконечного IFrame'а;
- Multipart XHR;
- SSE;
- WebSocket'ов.